# Javascript project structure - component architecture

Tags: javascript

Suppose I'm following a component-based architecture and I'm defining individual components as ES6 modules. I've got each component sat in a `/components` folder broken down into individual folders for a grouped components.

```
/js
  /components
    - header
      - navbar
    - filterbox
      - search
      - tabs
```

How or where would I call these components and where does the business logic live? In a master index.js file? It doesn't feel like a very *modern* approach.

Thank you in advance.

**tl;dr** - How do I structure a CBA project?

Comment: this question is very much asking for opinions... however, my general solution is to have the logic in separate service / controller folders. Have some "root" in the application that imports/discovers components/services/controllers, configures them and finally injects dependencies where needed. All my applications have a "Shell" interface that is passed around where needed and allows any controller / service to make changes through-out the application.

Comment: The problem is that _component_ is vague by definition. Every program is made up of components, whether it wants to be or not, but the abstract notion of what constitutes one simultaneously has dozens of arbitrary and unhelpful definitions.

Answer (score -4):

I would do, as you suggest, and keep the entire business logic in an index.js file and import components as necessary. No one seems to have a better solution for this.

Comment: This just seems as though it would get out of control very quickly.

Comment: This sent shivers down my spine. Not that I know of something better since I don't do CBAs, but all primal instincts screamed: wrong!